# Will there be a security fix for php in 10.04 LTS?

Tags: security, php

Is there already a security fix available for the latest critical PHP vulnerability in 10.04 LTS? If not when will it be available?

http://thexploit.com/sec/critical-php-remote-vulnerability-introduced-in-fix-for-php-hashtable-collision-dos/

Or does this critical vulnerability does not apply for version 5.3.2-1 that comes with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1):

The "latest critical vulnerability" that you are referring to was introduced in PHP 5.3.9. Lucid is therefore not affected by the flaw fixed in 5.3.10.